# Name of five card Texas Hold'em game?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I got shown this game during a break at a recent local tournament I was in that is just like Texas Hold'em except one is dealt five cards, not two. Then at the end of every betting round (pre-flop, flop, turn) one must choose and discard one card. By the time the river comes out you have your final two cards.

Is there a real game like this or is it just something made up (I know all games are made up, but I guess I'm wondering is it popular enough to have a name)

Comment: I don't know the name of the game 5 down hold and five up,
You can use all 5 cards in your hand or only 2, plus 3 up on the table out of 5, I also want to know the name of this game

Answer (score 3):

Where are you located ? - we have been playing this variant for the last 5-6 months in our local club WestPoker in Denmark. We have never seen or heard of this elswehere - we call it Five Card Throw.

We also play another variant which we call Crazy Five Card Throw, in this variant we have 3 card left on the river, but can use a maximium of 2 of them.

It is great fun, with lot of action, especially preflop, where all players more or less have playable hands.

Comment: I'm in Australia. Apparently it's got around. First heard about it about a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with each player get 5 cards and throw one of them each round, but there are a lot of variation to the game.

More known variation, similar to what you describe, is called pineapple poker - in this game each player received three cards and must throw one card pre-flop. crazy pineapple is the same game but in this case the card is thrown post flop (after the betting round).

Regards,
Amigal